# How to trim leading and trailing whitespaces before and after delimiter of values within each line of file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to  trim trailing and leading whitespaces  within a line of  a file.
for ex:
a,b,cat pig  ,d,e,f,g

space after c before comma(delimiter) of a file should be removed.

expected :
a,b,cat pig,d,e,f,g

I added line.strip() function in the code but it removes  only 
from leading and trailing spaces of a line.

```
checkWords = ("”" )
repWords = ('')

for line in f1:
    for check, rep in zip(checkWords, repWords):
       line = line.strip()
        line = line.replace(check, rep)
    f2.write(line)
f1.close()
f2.close()

f1 = open(r"C:\\Users\1597958\Desktop\a.txt", 'r')
f2 = open(r"C:\\Users\1597958\Desktop\b.txt", 'w')
checkWords = ("”" )
repWords = ('')

for line in f1:
    for check, rep in zip(checkWords, repWords):
       line = line.strip()
        line = line.replace(check, rep)
    f2.write(line)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED AFTER COMMENT :

well if i understood your comment well then you need to do this :

```
string = "a,b,cat pig ,d,e,f,g"
new_str = ",".join([x.strip() for x in string.split(",")])
```

The output will be : 
'a,b,cat pig,d,e,f,g'

Comment: hi i need to remove spaces only around delimiter here its comma

Comment: Hi, sorry for my misunderstanding, i edited my answer